# How do I display GroundOverlays in OpenLayers 3 (from a KML)?

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, openlayers

The back-end I'm working with serves KMLs in the following format (data is stripped for confidentiality):

```
<?xml ...>
<kml ...>
    <Document>
        <open>1</open>
        <GroundOverlay>
            <name>[Name]</name>
            <TimeStamp>
                <when>[ISO 8601 timestamp]</when>
            </TimeStamp>
            <drawOrder>0</drawOrder>
            <Icon>
                <href>[image_name].png</href>
                <refreshInterval>0.0</refreshInterval>
                <viewRefreshTime>0.0</viewRefreshTime>
                <viewBoundScale>0.0</viewBoundScale>
            </Icon>
            <altitude>0.0</altitude>
            <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
            <LatLonBox>...</LatLonBox>
        </GroundOverlay>
        <GroundOverlay>...</GroundOverlay>
        <GroundOverlay>...</GroundOverlay>
        <GroundOverlay>...</GroundOverlay>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

I'm attempting to display the images linked in these KMLs on a basic OpenLayers OSM map. This is the code I'm currently trying to use:

```
layer = new ol.layer.Vector
  source: new ol.source.KML
    projection: ol.proj.get("ESPG:3857")
    url: kmlPath.join("/") # I have verified this is the correct path

_map.addLayer(layer)
```

I've tried several variations of this – different projections, absolute URLs, etc. It seems as though OpenLayers *does* load the KML, but does not even attempt to load the linked images. The KML works just fine in Google Earth.

I'm stumped.

Comment: GroundOverlays are currently not supported. There's a GitHub issue for that already: <https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2941>.